# Detecting 2 TB of 3 TB Hard Drive in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I bought a hard drive with 3 TB capacity, but Windows 7 x64 only recognizes 2 terabytes of it.
Is this a hardware problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is a system using an MBR, then it may only read 2TB partitions. If it uses GPT for the partitions, then it should read all 3 TB. I assume the case is that the hard drive was set up as an MBR disk. This is true in Linux, Macintosh and Windows

Comment: Yes you are right @Luke. I changed My Partition Style to GPT from Disk Management. Thank You and +1

Comment: No problem :) Glad it worked out